# Would like to show a new view after a view animation is finished

Tags: ios, iphone

I have  a animation view.  When the animation is finished I would like to show a new view by setting its hidden to false.

I set the hidden to false after the animation block code, but it seems like the animation is being done on a separate thread.  The view gets unhidden while the animation block is still playing

```
// start animation block    
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut ];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:mCards[r] cache:YES];

//   mCards[0].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card.png"]; //begin
int id=TarretWheel[r];
mCards[r].image = gCardImages[id]; //end

// Start animtion
[UIView commitAnimations];

// show view
mBackground.hidden=false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is same as Joe but I would recommend using a different API which allows you with configure block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 
                      delay:0.0 
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | 
                      animations:^{

                         //   mCards[0].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card.png"]; //begin
                         int id=TarretWheel[r];
                         mCards[r].image = gCardImages[id]; //end

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                       mBackground.hidden=false;
                 }
 ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can (and preferably should, actually), be using the newer block-based animation methods on UIView. Check out the following (it has a completion block which is just what you need):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Edit:
There are other variants with `options` that you may want in your case.

Also, clarification on why you 'should' be using the block-based methods; from the docs (for `beginAnimations:context:`):

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.